# Django views: reuse function view variable in class-based view partial loaded with AJAX

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a "main" view server through a function view in `views.py` that sets a lot of variables. The template returned used a lot of these variables, but also the templates included in it and additional data loaded with AJAX.

```
def season_view(request, id):
  # we do a bunch of stuff
  return render_to_response('season.html', {groups: groups, date: date, ...}
```

Now, in this template a list of matches is displayed. There are a lot of matches, so they are loaded in groups separately using AJAX, so the following class-based view is called repeatedly to load the matches:

```
class GroupedMatches(TemplateView):
  template_name = 'partials/grouped_matches.html'

  def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    # stuff...
    context['matches'] = grouped_matches
    return context
```

And then `grouped_matches.html` loops through the `matches` and includes a match partial:

```
{% for match in matches }%
  {% include 'partials/match.html' %}
{% endfor %}
```

Here is the thing: the match partial doesn't only use the data the match itself holds, but also needs (for whatever purpose) some of the variables from way before, the `groups` we set in `season_view`.

The problem is that either dividing the logic in different views or using AJAX seem to lose the variables coming from `season_view` even though the match partials are included in that "master" view.

Why are these variables from the "higher" view lost? How can I use them in the partials without having to calculate them all over again?

Answer (score 1):

When the `GroupedMatches` view is called, its context needs to contain everything that you require in your template. If there is code in `season_view()` that you also require in `GroupedMatches` then you need to extract that specific code and use it in both views.

There are several options:

#### Option: High Level Function

Create a high level function that returns a dictionary which is added to the context everywhere you need it. This works but might not look very Django like. I won't elaborate on this because I would prefer inheritance. See below.

#### Option: Inheritance

You need to change `season_view()` to a class, as well, for example a `TemplateView` which overrides `get_context_data()`. You can then write your own Mixin which offers a super implementation of `get_context_data()` including all context properties that all of the inheriting views share.

```
# python3
from django.views.generic.base import ContextMixin, TemplateView

class GroupContextMixin(ContextMixin):
    def get_some_objects(self):
        # fetch info from db using self.request, self.kwargs etc.
        # maybe set some instance attributes for later use
        return objects

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        ctx = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        # add shared stuff using self.get_some_objects()
        return ctx

class SeasonView(GroupContextMixin, TemplateView):
    template_name = ...

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        ctx = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        # add season view specific stuff
        return ctx

class GroupedMatchesView(GroupContextMixin, TemplateView):
    template_name = ...

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        ctx = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        # add grouped matches view specific stuff
        return ctx
```

Comment: will this ensure that the season specific data will be added to the shared context only once?

Comment: Yes. Why do you think it could be added twice?

Comment: I don't know. Just making sure the context is shared between all these classes.

Comment: Super() can't be called without arguments. I get error "super() takes at least 1 argument (0 given)"

Comment: My code is python3. You have to adapt it to your python version. See also https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#super